# What is this horseshoe symbol in differential forms topic

Tags: differential-geometry

Help. I've been new to differential forms and there is this horeshoe symbol from my book that prevents me from moving from a certain topic.

The most similar one in context is the picture :
[Horseshoe symbol](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jY6qb.png) - in the most right part. Thank you

Comment: It is an Omega $\Omega$

Comment: @user619894 what does that omega represent? Is it some kind of set or something?

Comment: Presumably, your book (or whatever it is you have) has defined it at an earlier point. Wait, is that image from [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_form) (under "The exterior derivative")?

Comment: $\Omega^k(M)$ usually denotes the set of differential forms of degree $k$ on $M$.

Comment: It looks like the book sent to me expects me to be advanced. I am a beginner and I would appreciate if someone could tell me the topic for the definition so that I may search it manually. Thank you very much

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos ok thank you

Comment: in any decent paper or book the meaning of every symbol must be previously defined

Comment: @Arthur yes I got it from Wikipedia since it's the most "similar" form in equation that the book uses that I can find online

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\Omega^{k+1}(M)$ denotes the set of $(k+1)$-differential forms on the manifold $M$.